# How to edit a specific column from selected id with a new value given by the user Bash

Tags: bash

I have this text file

```
1221#John#baseball
31231#Nick#football 
......
```

And i want to create a command in bash like this

```
command new value column id
```

Which will change the column given by the user of specific id with a new value
I have tried to use sed, awk, grep  and some combination of them but nothing work .

Comment: Is `new value` one argument or two? Also, could you provide sample input and desired output? That way it is clearer what you are trying to do.

Comment: You should also show what you've researched and/or tried to accomplish your task.

Comment: " have tried to use sed, awk, grep and some combination of them but nothing work . " Please [edit] your question and show us one of the solutions you have tried. What output does it produce?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I can't leave comments, so I will try to do this in the form of an answer.

From what you state, you want a USER to be able to edit ONLY their line by running the command as follows:

```
command [new value] [column id]
```

So this would be the script I would write:

```
#!/bin/bash

newval="$1"
column="$2"
#Set your file below since you don't want to do it in the command use the full path
file="filename.txt"

#Reject any column 2 as you don't want users editing their ID
if [[ "$column" == "2" ]]; then
    echo "Invalid column ID, can not change username"
    exit 1
fi

#Find the username and look up the designated column
oldval=`grep "$USER" "$file" | awk -F "#" '{print $'$column'}'`
#Find line number so we know which to edit
linenum=`grep -n "$USER" "$file" | awk -F ":" '{print $1}'`
#Make the string to feed into sed as the preceding variable causes errors
string=$linenum"s/$oldval/$newval/g"
#Find the old value and replace it with the new value
sed -i "$string" $file
```

This way you would run the command as you have designated. As with any command if there would be a space in any of the values you should use quotes to get the correct value.

Additionally if the number is the user ID, change the script as follows:

Add:

```
UserID=`id -u`
```

Change:

```
if [[ "$column" == "1" ]]; then
```

Change:

```
oldval=`grep "$UserID" "$file" | awk -F "#" '{print $'$column'}'`
linenum=`grep -n "$UserID" "$file" | awk -F ":" '{print $1}'`
```

Comment: My post was  terrible i know .It was my first  but you find exactly what i was looking for .Thanks a lot Kip